# UITableView not scrolling when UITableViewController is a child view of a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a UIViewController with a container View. The container view's child is a static tableView. The last cell of the tableView has a text field. While working with only UITableViewController, tableViewController handled the movement of the tableView when text field was selected. Now, even though the keyboard appears, the tableView is not adjusting itself. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyboard notification for scrolling the tableview up

```
// Keyboard
    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
                                                         name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
                                                         object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide),
                                                         name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
                                                         object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
                let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0)
                tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
                tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
       tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
       tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
```

them you call on viewDidLoad function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented this elsewhere. Is it possible to make TableViewController handle it instead of using keyboard notifications?

Comment: @Watson u can make it in ScrollViewDelegate, no problem. TableView it is subclass of ScrollView.